# What does ‘Cocktail-party fool’ exactly mean? Is it established English word?

Tags: meaning-in-context, is-it-a-word

I found the word ‘cocktail-party fool’ in the following sentence of the article in the Book review section of the New Yorker (August 16), which is titled ‘How Do You Say Ralph Fiennes?’

> “The mini-videos are essential viewing for people fearful of making a variety of conversational missteps that would immediately peg them as philistines, charlatans, or general *cocktail-party fools*.”

As ‘Cocktail party fools’ is laid in parallel with 'philistines' and 'charlatans' with antecedent ‘or,’ the author seems to have used the word as a synonym with philistines and charlatans. But naturally there should be difference among all three words.
Though I can deduce the meaning of the word from its word elements, what does ‘Cocktail party fools’ exactly mean? How different it is from a ‘Party-pooper’ who is ridiculed by others by making an illiterate remark at a party?’

I checked the definition of ‘Cocktail-party fool’ on online dictionaries. Neither Cambridge nor Merriam-Webster online dictionary registers this word. Is ‘Cocktail-party fool’ an established English word, or the word just in making?

Answer (score 8):

**No!**  Googling [quickly confirms](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22cocktail-party+fool%22) (only 5 hits!) that it isn’t an established phrase.

So what *does* it mean, as the sum of its parts?  Someone who is a fool at cocktail parties.  Why cocktail parties specifically?  Cocktail parties have long been used as a byword (at least since the days of [Thurber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Thurber)) for small-talk and superficial conversation — especially, superficially intellectual conversation.

So **a *cocktail-party fool* is someone who makes a fool of themself in superficial conversation**, by attempting to show off their knowledge but, in the event, proving wrong.

A *party-pooper*, by the way, is something rather different: it is someone who tries to stop other people from having fun — for instance, the neighbour who knocks on the door at ten o’clock and asks you to all stop talking so loudly.

Comment: ＠PLL. Thank you. Your definition appears to hit nail on the head of the meaning of the word to me. I’m relieved to know why I wasn’t able to find the word in dictionaries online.